# Cannot read Property of undeifned Cards material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, typeerror

I am using cards from material ui in my react project. I am trying to use two functions in my cards, onMouseOver and onMouseOut. But my code is giving me an error saying "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onMouseOver' of undefined". Here is an abstract on that part from my code.

```
class ExpandableCard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {shadow: 1}
    }

    onMouseOver = () => this.setState({shadow: 3});

    onMouseOut = () => {this.setState({shadow: 1})
    };

    render(){
        var Populate = this.props.mediaFiles.map(function (value) {
            return (
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <Card key = {value.id}
                      onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
                      onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut}
                      zDepth={this.state.shadow}
                >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're just having the basic javascript problem of missing the context (this) inside the map function in the `render` method.

I'd suggest you to change your `map` function in render to an arrow function (this way its gonna keep the outer context to the inner function) and that should be enough. :)

```
render() {
  var Populate = this.props.mediaFiles.map((value) => {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider>
        <Card key = {value.id}
          onMouseOver={this.onMouseOver}
          onMouseOut={this.onMouseOut}
          zDepth={this.state.shadow}
        >
        ...
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks a lot. But I didn't get the reason it worked. Arrow functions are just another way to represent normal functions.

Comment: Take a look into the arrow function docs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

```An arrow function does not create its own this context, so this has the 
original meaning from the enclosing context.```